# Matplotlib output messed up in Kubuntu 18

Tags: kubuntu, python, matplotlib, plot

I run the same Python3 code on several computers for plotting data. On one of them, I have got Ubuntu 16.04, the others are Kubuntu 18.04 and 18.10. In Kubuntu, the plot is completely messed up, the one that I get in Ubuntu is definitely the right one.

The characteristics of the mess also differs from time to time and from computer to computer. So these points sometimes follow a horizontal trend, sometimes it is completely messed up, but I could not find any systematic difference in the environment.

The physical size of the plot in Kubuntu is also smaller than it should be.

I have encountered the same issue for the plot of some (but not all) of my other programs as well. So for some code, it is the same as what I get from the Ubuntu machine, sometimes it is like the picture below.

I installed matplotlib via pip3 and tkinter in the same manner on all computers, therefore I guess that the only difference is the distribution and version. I also tried to run it in Python2, but the output is the same. (Although there may be other aspects that I do not consider.)

The top image is from Kubuntu, the bottom is from Ubuntu for the same dataset.

[image: The output from Kubuntu]

[image]

Have you got any idea what can go wrong?

Comment: Do you import the data from a file?

Comment: Is it exactly the same data ? meaning, you can test the data set #1 on an ubuntu pc, and the data set #2 on kubuntu pc, and the results are still the same ?

Comment: Yes, I import the data from the same datafile on both PC. I save the code and the data file to Dropbox and work from that folder so there should not be difference neither in the input file nor the code.

Comment: Perhaps for some reason the data type has changed. Is it possible for you to explicitly change the data type to numeric and rerun the code?

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint! I believed that every data was imported as float, but it turned out that some numbers remained as string. However, some of the computers still handled the data type well, that's why the different plots were a bit strange, but after correcting the import, all of them are nice.